# Why is XPS 13 not able to run at maximum CPU-Speed?

Tags: 14.04, dell, cpu, xps

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 an an 2015 DELL XPS (Developer Edition)
and dealing with Speed-Issues, stumbled upon some strage behaviour regarding CPU-Speed. 
It seems, the CPU-frequency is never higher than 1100 MHz. 
Using "indicator-cpufreq" It shows possibly available speeds up to 2.2 GHz, but I can only choose up to 1.1 GHz. Same with command-line information:

```
lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) pro Kern:    2
Kern(e) pro Socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA-Knoten:           1
Anbieterkennung:       GenuineIntel
Prozessorfamilie:      6
Modell:                61
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               1100.000
BogoMIPS:              4389.76
Virtualisierung:       VT-x
L1d Cache:             32K
L1i Cache:             32K
L2 Cache:              256K
L3 Cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep MHz

`MHz        : 1100.000
    cpu MHz     : 1100.000
    cpu MHz     : 1100.000
    cpu MHz     : 1100.000`

Any idea what could be wrong? I was waiting for the next LTS. Could an update to 15.04 solve the problem? Thanks :)

Comment: CPU power autoscales on hardware side when it is needed. Do you ever need that power?

Comment: Which frequency scaling driver are you using? And which governor? `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`. And as previous comment asked, does the CPU frequency go up if you load down the CPUs?

Comment: @DougSmythies
scaling driver is "acpi-cpufreq".
governour is "userspace".

high cpu-load does nothing to increase frequency. I just tried again to be sure, but no change, even if the load is at 400%. Whats really strange to me is, that i can select all the frequencies in the ui-tool, but just up to 1100MHz

Comment: Try the ondemand and/or the performance governors. What do you get with them? as su ( `sudo su` ) do: `for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "ondemand" > $file; done`

Comment: unfortunately no change: "ondemand" the cpu is between 500-1100MHz while its 1100Mhz in "performance". Again while running CPU-intense programs

Comment: can you find and list "available_frequencies"? (I can not look for an example command at the moment, but they should be in a similar area to where we have been getting stuff so far.)

Comment: I did some more testing. Apparently while on battery, the OS restricts the CPU to 1100MHz. When I connect the notebook to a power supply afterwards, the restriction seems to be still in place. Cold booting with power-supply "solves" the problem. Is there a way to override this behaviour?

Comment: I had just experienced the same with a new Dell XPS 13 (9360) and the pre-installed Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I remembered having set up `silent_mode/eco_mode`  in dualboot Windows which had been hibernated before booting Ubuntu.
Rebooted to Windows, turned off `silent_mode/eco_mode`, rebooted to Ubuntu -- 2.7GHz again.

May be a coincidence, but just rebooting with external power plugged in helped.